# In Regex, is it possible to use variable name rather than pure string?

Tags: regex

My case:

```
String TARGET1 = "abc";
String TARGET2 = "def";
```

I want to find the string that contains either "-abc" or "-def". (If the string is "-xyzabc", than this is not valid).

I know I can use a pure string to do this: `".*-(abc|def).*"`, but can I use the variable name to do the similar thing?

something like: `String pattern = ".*-" + (TARGET1 || TARGET2) + ".*";` Is there a way to do so?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is your source language C#? If not, then what?

Comment: E.g. `String pattern = ".*-(" + TARGET1 + "|" + TARGET2 + ").*";`, just use string concatenation.

Comment: String pattern = ".*-(" + TARGET1 + "|" + TARGET2 + ").*"; This worked thanks a lot!